# Carto DB city border polygons issue?

Tags: polygon, carto, spatial-database, gadm

I want to visualize some statistical data about my country and I'm using the CartoDB geocoder. I've city names and I want to see cities as polygons but CartoDB says it has no polygon data, it can only provide point data. I can download polygon data from the GADM [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) web site. Any ideas how can it be done on CartoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CartoDB doesn't currently have polygons for city regions, so if you have the city boundaries available you will have to import the boundaries to your CartoDB account and merge them with your current data.

You have two options: to use the Merge Datasets option in CartoDB or to run a SQL query. Let me explain the solution in both of them.

**If you want to use the Merge Datasets (column join option) tool** as specified [here](https://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/merging_data/).
In the step 4 (see image below) of the tutorial you need to select the columns in both datasets from which the join will be performed. The information of the tables will be merged according to this column. Here, you want to select the columns that contain the city names.

[image: step 4]

In the step 5 of the tutorial you need to select the columns that you want your new table to have. Merging two tables always give a third table as a result. In this case, you want to select `the_geom` from the boundaries table that you imported, and everything except for `the_geom` column from the column where you have your statistical data.

[image: step 5]

**If you are familiar with SQL** you can update your data table with the geometries of the cities. For example:

```
UPDATE your_current_data_table_name SET the_geom = (
  SELECT geometries_table_name.the_geom 
  FROM geometries_table_name 
  WHERE geometries_table_name.city_column_name ilike your_city_column_name
)
```

Where you need to substitute:

- **your_current_data_table_name** by the name of the table in which you have your statistical data
- **geometries_table_name** by the name of the table that you imported and that contains the city boundaries
- **city_column_name** by the name of the column (in the geometries table) that stores the city names
- **your_city_column_name** by the name of the column in your statistical information table that stores the city names

Note that the name of the names in your current table and in the geometries table that you will import will need to coincide (the query above is case insensitive, but still spaces or other characters have importance).